# Get Distinct values from column

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want distinct value. This following method gives me the same value
 again and again.
Any suggestions?

```
ArrayList<String> getNumberFromNote(String note) {
    Cursor cursor;
    mDbHelper = mSqliteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereClause =  SqliteHelpers.NUMBER_COLUMN +" = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {note};
    cursor = mDbHelper.query(SqliteHelpers.TABLE_NAME, null, whereClause, whereArgs,
            null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String itemname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                SqliteHelpers.NUMBER_COLUMN));
        if (itemname != null) {
            arrayList.add(itemname);
            System.out.println(itemname);
        }
    }
    return arrayList;

}
```

Comment: the only value would be `note`. Just skip the whole query entirely, and `return note`...

Comment: snippet would be helpful i dont understand exactly where to return... before looping ?

Comment: you are getting the column `number` from the rows where `number == note`. Basically, you are just getting `note`. Why are you even making a query?

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor= db.rawQuery("select Distinct "+Database.Colomnname+" from "+Database.Colomnname, null);
```

Comment: the thing that i want would be something like " "SELECT Distinct NOTES_COLUMN FROM " + SqliteHelpers.TABLE_NAME; where number = 22"; something like this

Answer (score 0):

Use method `public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

`distinct` parameter should be `true`. `groupBy` and other can be `null` if you don't need them